# Shiny: reactive() check on read.csv

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, shiny, file-exists

I am writing a server script of shiny where I want reactive() to first check the data on my c drive, if it's there then well and good else do the other data processing and save it for the next iteration. 
And the name of data is dependent on input$var

So that next time it will be really quick to create the charts
Following is just a running example of my big problem

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
mt=mtcars
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
data1 =reactive({
 if(file.exists("input$var.csv")
   {data=read.csv(input$var.csv)})
  else{    
    data=mt[mt$cyl==input$var,] 
  write.csv(data,file="c:\\input$var.csv")
    }
  })  
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data2=data1()
    ggplot(data2$d,aes(x=gear,y=wt))+geom_boxplot() })

})
```

Comment: I think you need to use paste to determine the file.exists function, now it will look for a file called input$var.csv. Try: `file.exists(paste0(input$var,".csv"))` , same goes for `read.csv(paste0(input$var,".csv"))` or is the question about something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste0` as timfaber said you. In R functions which deals with files you have to give a complete string then `paste0` allows you to give a string like "*name_with_what_is_in_input$var.csv*".

```
ibrary(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
mt=mtcars
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
data1 =reactive({
 if(file.exists(paste0(input$var,".csv"))
   {data=read.csv(paste0(input$var,".csv"))})
  else{    
    data=mt[mt$cyl==input$var,] 
  write.csv(data,file=paste0("c:\\",input$var,".csv"))
    }
  })  
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data2=data1()
    ggplot(data2$d,aes(x=gear,y=wt))+geom_boxplot() })

})
```

Comment: You welcome :) you can do a lot of things with shiny. For esthetic you can have a look to `shinyjs` and `shinydashboard` packages.